#  I keep loosing my events, how can I keep them attached

Tags: jquery

I have a small 'screen' that pops up over part of my page. This screen has two buttons on it. When either of these buttons get pressed the screen is removed. But the screen could need to be reused at a later time so instead of always rebuilding the screen i store it in data of an object on the page. While the stored screen reloads fine, all of the events seem to be missing as the second time the screen appears the buttons dont do n e thing. How can i fix this?

```
function AddScreen() {
    var store= $('#store'), screen;
    if(objectStoringScreen.length > 0){
        screen = objectStoringScreen.data('screen');
    }else {
        store = CreateStore(); //Create Store
        $(this).parent().append(store); //Add Store
        screen = Screen(); // Create Screen
    }

    PushScreen(screen); //Load selected screen

    function Screen() {
        //build div
        // build two buttons and place them in the div
        // btn1.click(onOK); btn2.click(onCancel);
    }

    function onOK() {
        store.data('screen',screen); 
        PopScreen();
    }
    function onCancel() {
        PopScreen(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you attaching your event handlers ? Are you using `live` ?

Comment: Change one of your event handlers to `.live('click', function()....` and see if that works.

Comment: So ive discorverd that even though im holding a jquery copy of the full object, i still lose all the events when I remove the physical piece, and i dont feel live/delegate work appropriately in this case. Instead ive decided to just hide the screen on the page and re open it when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create the screen beforehand and toggle it when needed.

```
<div id="screen">
    Screen Div
    <input type="button" value="OK" /> <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
</div>
<div id="showScreen">click here to show the screen</div>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Screen already exists, just hide it.  If you need to build it from data on the page, do it after it's hidden.
        $('#screen').hide();

        // Some action that shows/hides your screen, I just used a click method as an example
        $('#showScreen').click(function () {
            if ($('#screen').css('display') == 'none') {
                // Or you can build here if you need it to be updated in real time for whatever reason
                //   ex.  $('#screen').append('<input type="button" id="someSpecialButton" value="Special Button" />');
                $('#screen').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#screen').hide();
            }
        });

        // Screen button events, will still exist after hiding the screen
        $('#screen input[type="button"]').click(function () {
            alert('You clicked ' + $(this).attr('value') + ' on the screen');
        });
    });
```